# How to pass data from a class into a Mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'll be going through what I have done to solve this problem.

1. There is an empty board ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCnOh.png)).
2. You can place the **knight** piece anywhere on the board.
3. You have to choose a desired position.
4. The Game should return the coordinates of **the shortest distance** it takes to get to that desired position
5. For Example. Let's place the knight on A1. I want to get to C5. The coordinates that  would be returned are: ***A1, B3, C5.***

*Easy Enough?*

- This game has to be designed using a **RESTFUL api** with **NodeJS**
- There will be **no interface**. It is purely back-end.
- I am using a chess library as I am finding it difficult to create my own board (etc..) You can find it here: https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js

*What have I done to solve this?*

**I created a controller and a board class**

This code does not work but is shown to simulate what I want to achieve:

(I am an amateur technically).

My Controller:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  var board = new Board(chess = new Chess());
  // The post request creates a board
  board.clearBoard();
  // This clears the board of existing pieces
  board.placeFirstPosition(position);
  // This adds the knight to the board
  board.endPosition(position);
  // This method in the class here will handle the logic of moving the knight to the end position 
// This logic needs to be passed into the model 
  var move = new Move({
  coordinate: (all_the_coordinates)
  })
  // This data (coordinates) will be passed into the model (via mongoose)
  move.save().then((doc) => {
    res.send(doc);
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
  // Finally these moves will be saved to the database and will be returned to the server
});
```

My Board Class:

```
var Chess = require('../../node_modules/chess.js').Chess;

function Board(chess = new Chess()) {
  this._chess = chess;
}

Board.prototype.clearBoard = function() {
  this._chess.clear();
}

Board.prototype.placeFirstPosition = function(position) {
  this._chess.put({ type: 'k', color: 'w' }, position)
}

Board.prototype.endPosition = function(position) {
 // logic calculating the sequence of coordinates
}

Board.prototype.showBoard = function() {
  return this._chess.ascii();
}

module.exports = {Board};
```

- It may seem a bit long winded that I have added this chess library which can display the board but this was my only option as I am unsure how to create one otherwise.

**My Problem:**

The questions are:

- How can I pass the coordinates from my method in my class into my **move** model? This subsequently will be saved in the database.
- How can I pass the desired position into the functions in the POST  without hardcoding it? Such as `board.placeFirstPosition('a1');`
- I'll be handling the logic later on, what route would you recommend?
- I can't use postman to pass any data in as the class is doing that.
- Is it necessary to have **a database**? My thinking is there has to be otherwise how will we be able to know what coordinates it took to get to that position?

**Your Advice:**

- If you can think of a better way of me achieving this end result, I would love to hear your advice.

Comment: So no interface, no game? You just have initial coordinates, desired destination and you need to get the steps in response?

Comment: All your logic will be done server side, if working with `node.js` first create a javascript algorithm (probably recursive) that gets as input the initial and desired positions and calculates the shortest path and return the steps. After you can create a simple route with either `http` or the `express` libraries that receives those two parameters, make them go through the function and send the result in response.

Comment: Thanks for the kind response. Would you mind setting this as a detailed answer? I am still finding it hard to understand what you mean because it is hard to come to a conclusion in the comments. Is it not necessary to have a database? Could you write an example for me please.

Comment: Please don't add excessive conditions about how your question may be answered. While we do encourage people to answer in the answer space, I hope that a small clue given as a comment is welcome to you, given that it is volunteers who are helping. I also would suggest you refrain from asking people to "read the whole question" - to native English speakers, that is brusque, condescending or patronising, and is likely to earn you the downvotes you were looking to avoid `:-)`. FWIW, the question seems fine to me, and does not need to be couched in cautions and disclaimers.

Comment: (I suppose it could be regarded as too broad given the number of questions you're asking, but for edge-cases I tend not to vote, especially since it now has an accepted answer anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I am getting this correct, your conditions are:

- Initial position is chosen
- Destination position is chosen
- An HTTP request is made and returns the quickest path.

Stages would be to

Create an algorithm to match your logic

`function findBestPath(initPosX, initPosY, destPosX, destPosY)`

Create a route to use this function

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('bodyParser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/getBestPath', (req, res) => {
    let initPosX = req.body.initPosX,
        initPosY = req.body.initPosY,
        destPosX = req.body.destPosX,
        destPosY = req.body.destPosY;

    res.send(findBestPath(initPosX, initPosY, destPosX, destPoxY));
};

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Once you're done with that you can can call this function using a POST HTTP request from any interface you can think of (including postman).

Comment: That is a great answer. Thank you. There is no need for a database at all?

Comment: The algorithm can simply return the coordinates each time?

Comment: @user9219996 Unless you have any reason to keep track of the steps, yes it can. The need for a DB comes when you wanna save data and use it later, if all you need is this one action there's no need to save anything.